# Extract main text from HTML using Cheerio

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

How to extract just main text using cheerio?
I wish to go to unknown sites, and get main text (or all text) simply using nodeJS and Cheerio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved using npm moudle called boilerpipe

Answer (score 0):

Use the Request Library and you get the HTML text back. Check the site to see if it's not using a Virtual DOM or Shadow DOM ie. React.  If it is, Cheerio's methods don't work and you get an unusable circular object.